# How do I generate random numbers to fill in empty rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've added two new columns on one of my database's table. They are called Exam and assignment results.

[image: This is the table]

At the moment the two columns are both empty. I want them filled with random examination results but no greater than 100. How to I generate random number for both columns from 0 to 100?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `rand(),`checksum()`, and`newid()`:

```
update t
    set exam = rand(checksum(newid())) * 101,
        assignment = rand(checksum(newid())) * 101;
```

In SQL Server, `rand()` is (essentially) called once for a query.  To get around this, you can give it a new seed.  You could also use other columns in each row as the seed value, if you wanted reproducible results.

Comment: Sorry, not very experienced with sql or databases but I'd assume the t means the table name and the exam and assignment the column names?

Comment: Hi, nevermind, it worked! My fields are now filled with random numbers thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following expression (for instance as column) to generate random numbers from 0..100 (inclusive):

```
ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(8)) as bigint))%101
```

The `RAND()` function without seed does not work as expected here because it is invoked only once per query, and thus you get one random number repeated.

Comment: @Squirrel I'd love to know as well! :) I think the information that `RAND()` doesn't work as expected - try `SELECT RAND() rnd, * FROM SYS.ALL_OBJECTS` to see what I mean - in itself should already be valuable, and it is correct.